# OpenCV cv::dnn::Net::getBlob return dnn::Blob::matRefConst has rows == -1 and cols == -1

Tags: c++, opencv, blob, caffe, proto

Screenshot: wrong result of getBlob returned:

[image: image here]

here is addition code:

```
resize(img, img, Size(224, 224));

dnn::Blob inputBlob = dnn::Blob::fromImages(img); 
net.setBlob(".data", inputBlob); 
net.forward(); 
dnn::Blob prob = net.getBlob( "loss1"/*"prob"*/);
```

and prototxt file:
    # name: "nin_imagenet"
    # next five line  is changed compared to caffe's prototxt
    # i delete the layers who has **top: "data"** 
    input: "data"  # input name
    input_dim: 1   # batchsize
    input_dim: 3   # number of channels 
    input_dim: 224 # width
    input_dim: 224 # height

```
# unchaged text
# ...

# another changed compared to caffe's prototxt
# i delete layers who has **bottom: "label"**  
layers {
  name: "loss1"
  type: SOFTMAX
  bottom: "fc81"
  top: "loss1"
}
# changed below
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it because you deal with 4D blob, not a matrix, size is stored in size array (see below example).
Try to extract planes using this code piece:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------
// Extract plane with defined n and c from nchw blob
//-------------------------------------------------------
void mtcnn::extractPlane(Mat &src, int n, int ch, Mat &dst)
{
    const int rows = src.size[2];
    const int cols = src.size[3];
    dst = cv::Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_32FC1);

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        const float *ptrsrc = src.ptr<float>(n, ch, row);
        float *ptrdst = dst.ptr<float>(row);
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            ptrdst[col] = ptrsrc[col];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you use something like this to set input data:

```
        inputBlob = blobFromImage(img, 0.0078125, Size(ws, hs), Scalar(127.5, 127.5, 127.5)); //Convert Mat to batch of images
        p_net.setInput(inputBlob, "data"); //set the network input
```

Comment: thank Andrey.i tried extractPlane method.really sorry i dont know how to choose param n and param ch.i tried they all both zero.the code run well,but result absolutely wrong.and i wanna get “classID”  using my trianed caffe model.my code changed from "https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html" sample.

Comment: Did you print your output tensor size ? Also it may be you did not normalize input data, or packed it in wrong way, and that is the reason you getting wrong results. This code from my working project, and it tested.

Comment: Also you may need to swap R and B planes. Check blobFromImage manual.